# VB6 error: Property OleObjectBlob in XXXXX could not be set

Tags: vb6, activex, ocx

I am trying to run an .ocx library for a VB6 project that I have. However, every time that it calls the first object property, it generates the error below:

```
Line 937: Property OleObjectBlob in ICImagingControl1 could not be set.
Line 937: Cannot load control ICImagingControl1; license not found.
```

Some forums mention that the cause is using an old VB6 version, or a missing file FM20ENU.DLL in System32 (my case SYSWOW64). I already upgraded too the latest VB6 version (which is still quite old) and made sure the file was in the right folder. Neither of them worked for me, any ideas why is this issue happening?

Thanks

Comment: Did you notice that they actually revived the ActiceX control? So give the new one a shot, they will very likely even support it again. http://www.imagingcontrol.com/en_US/

Comment: @Dabblernl: Good observation. I am using version 3.06 of their package. At least that is what the tech support person gave me, which still supports activeX. The difference is that runs over a 64-bit OS. I am still waiting for his answer, that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed and uninstalled several times the software, which created a reference to the wrong ocx in the registry. To solve this, I uninstalled IC Imaging Control, proceeded to erase the references in the tree, and reinstalled the proper version.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked by a client of mine to edit an old vb6 project and ran in the same problem.

Googled for a solution until I found this:

https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/195/Q195353/

Downloaded and executed the program and the project could be perfectly edited.

Original text of this Microsoft article:

> ```
> Q195353: FILE: VBUSC.EXE Provides Licensing for Discontinued Controls
> Article: Q195353
> Product(s): Microsoft Visual Basic for Windows
> Version(s): 6.0
> Operating System(s): 
> Keyword(s): kbfile kbusage kbCtrl kbLicensing kbVBp kbVBp500 kbVBp600 kbGrpDSVB kbFAQ kbVBp600FAQ k
> Last Modified: 21-JUN-2002
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> The information in this article applies to:
>
> - Microsoft Visual Basic Learning Edition for Windows, version 6.0 
> - Microsoft Visual Basic Professional Edition for Windows, version 6.0 
> - Microsoft Visual Basic Enterprise Edition for Windows, version 6.0 
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> SUMMARY
> =======
>
> VBUSC.EXE is a file that installs the Design-Time Licenses for ActiveX controls
> that shipped with earlier versions of Visual Basic, but are no longer supported
> and have been discontinued with the current version.
>
> MORE INFORMATION
> ================
>
> The following file is available for download from the Microsoft Download
> Center:
>
>   VBUSC.exe
>   (http://download.microsoft.com/download/VB60Pro/Install/2/Win98/En-US/VBUSC.exe)
>
> Release Date: August 15, 2000
>
> For additional information about how to download Microsoft Support files, click
> the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge
> Base:
>
>   Q119591 How to Obtain Microsoft Support Files from Online Services
>
> Microsoft scanned this file for viruses. Microsoft used the most current
> virus-detection software that was available on the date that the file was
> posted. The file is stored on secure servers that prevent any unauthorized
> changes to the file.
>
>    FileName               Size
>   ---------------------------------------------------------
>   VBUSC.EXE                88k
>
> The following controls are no longer supported by Microsoft Visual Basic:
>
> ActiveX Control Name                Filename
> ------------------------------------------------
> Desaware Animated Button Control    ANIBTN32.OCX
> Microhelp Gauge Control             GAUGE32.OCX
> Pinnacle-BPS Graph Control          GRAPH32.EXE
> Microsoft Grid Control              GRID32.OCX
> Microhelp Key State Control         KEYSTA32.OCX
> Microsoft Outline Control           MSOUTL32.OCX
> Outrider SpinButton Control         SPIN32.OCX
> Sheridan 3D Controls                THREED32.OCX
>
> The ActiveX controls listed above are no longer supported, but ship with the
> Professional and Enterprise Editions of Microsoft Visual Basic for backward
> compatibility when upgrading existing projects.
>
> These controls do not ship with the Learning Edition of Microsoft Visual Basic.
>
> For the Professional and Enterprise Editions, the controls are located on the
> installation CDs at the following locations:
>
> Microsoft Visual Basic Edition        Location
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Professional 6.0                      \Common\Tools\VB\Controls
> Enterprise 6.0                        \Common\Tools\VB\Controls
> Visual Studio Professional 6.0        \Common\Tools\VB\Controls (CD2)
> Visual Studio Enterprise 6.0          \Common\Tools\VB\Controls (CD3)
>
>
> Each of these directories contain a README.TXT with instructions on how to
> install the controls for design-time use.
>
> NOTE: Using the Learning Edition to upgrade a project developed in an earlier
> version of Microsoft Visual Basic might result in licensing problems for these
> controls.
>
> The VBUSC.EXE installs the design-time licenses for the controls listed above if
> Visual Basic is detected on the computer.
>
> REFERENCES
> ==========
>
> For additional information, please see the following articles in the Microsoft
> Knowledge Base:
>
>   Q194784 INFO: Controls Shipped in Visual Basic 6.0
>
>   Q172193 INFO: List of VB 4.0 Custom Controls Discontinued in VB 5.0
> ```